# std::variant converting constructor behavior

Tags: c++, c++17

C++17 `std::variant<class... Types>` has a converting constructor

```
template< class T >
constexpr variant(T&& t) noexcept(/* see below */);
```

(number 4 in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant). Its description is a rather impenetrable wall of text. Is this meant to behave as if variant had a bunch of

```
template< class T_i > constexpr variant(T_i&& t) noexcept;
```

constructors, one for each T_i in Types?

Answer (score 5):

Let's break the description down:

> Constructs a variant holding the alternative type `Tj` that would be selected by overload resolution for the expression `F(std::forward<T>(t))` if there was an overload of imaginary function `F(Ti)` for every `Ti` from `Types...` in scope at the same time.

Assume that we have the example in the documentation:

```
variant<string, bool> x("abc"); // OK, but chooses bool
```

- `Types...` is `<string, bool>`

---

> if there was an overload of imaginary function `F(Ti)` for every `Ti` from `Types...`

```
int F(string) { return 0; }
int F(bool)   { return 1; }
```

---

> selected by overload resolution for the expression `F(std::forward<T>(t))`

```
template <typename T>
void select(T&& t)
{
    std::cout << F(std::forward<T>(t)) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    select("abc"); // prints `1`
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TG54BZjBevvhIcgb)

---

> Constructs a variant holding the alternative type `Tj` [...]

The chosen alternative type `Tj` is therefore `bool`.